sh for open telemetry-collector-contrib image
I have that image (based on alpine)

otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.90.0

And try to open sh by some of that commands:
docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
docker exec -it container_name /bin/ash
docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh
docker exec -it container_name ash
docker exec -it container_name sh

And no of these commands working for me...
How can I open terminal for that image?

You may not be able to.  A Docker image doesn't necessarily contain a shell or other basic Unix tools, especially if the packaged application is a compiled program that doesn't need them.

If we run the image:
docker run -it --rm --name otel otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.90.0

And then get the container pid:
pid=$(docker container inspect otel --format '{{ .State.Pid }}')

We can inspect the container root filesystem like this:
sudo ls -l /proc/$pid/root/

Which shows us that the image contains only a single binary:
total 220580
drwxr-xr-x.   5 lars lars       360 Aug  2 20:00 dev
drwxr-xr-x.   1 lars lars        78 Aug  2 20:00 etc
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 lars lars 225873920 Nov 28  2023 otelcol-contrib
dr-xr-xr-x. 504 root root         0 Aug  2 20:00 proc
drwxr-xr-x.   1 lars lars        40 Aug  2 20:00 run
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root         0 Jul 28 19:04 sys

(And a smattering of files in /etc).
There is no shell available in the container.
